# Same filter in different chains

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to split input video, scale each stream using different parameters and add subtitles to each output, using the same parameters. I can do it repeating `subtitles` filter in each chain, can I avoid this duplication?

```
ffmpeg \
    -i input.mp4
    -filter_complex "[v:0]split=2[v480][v720];
[v480]scale=858x480,subtitles=sub.srt:force_style='Fontsize=18,MarginV=15'[o480];
[v720]scale=1280x720,subtitles=sub.srt:force_style='Fontsize=18,MarginV=15'[o720]" \
    -map [o480] -c:v libx264 -b:v 2000k -bufsize:v 3000k -map 0:a -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 480.mp4 \
    -map [o720] -c:v libx264 -b:v 4000k -bufsize:v 5000k -map 0:a -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 720.mp4
```

I this example I want to avoid repeating `subtitles=sub.srt:force_style='Fontsize=18,MarginV=15'`, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Apply the subtitles filter before the split. Note that subtitles will be, proportionally, the same size in each output stream.

`-filter_complex "[0:v]subtitles=sub.srt:force_style='Fontsize=18,MarginV=15',split=2[v480][v720];
[v480]scale=858x480[o480];[v720]scale=1280x720[o720]"`

Comment: Sure, but if I want video quality to be lower, I don't want the subtitles quality to degrade, that's why I make subtitles burning after scaling

Comment: Then you'll need to apply subtitles twice